# Traefik ACME HTTP SNI 01 .well-known not available (v1.5.0)

Tags: https, lets-encrypt, traefik

I am using a complex Traefik - Dropcart setup with automatic SSL certification via  Let's Encrypt. Because of the TLS-SNI termintation I switched to the rc5 Docker version of Let's Encrypt which support HTTP-SNI, DNS isn't an option for me.
Unfortunately it gives an 400 timeout error (see logs).

**Config**

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  compress = true
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[...]

[acme]
  email = "email@address.com"
  caServer = "https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onHostRule = true
  acmeLogging = true
  #dnsProvider = "manual"

  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
```

**Logs**

```
domain.example.com:acme: Error 400 - urn:acme:error:connection - 
Fetching http://domain.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5uyEKpgr[...]c4CfMOZjc: Timeout
 Error Detail:
    Validation for domain.example.com:80
    Resolved to:
        *IPv4*
        *IPv6*
    Used: *IPv6*
]"
```

Does anyone know how I can get HTTP validation fixed?

Thanks!

*EDIT:*
Same config seemed to work on a consul backend. So maybe something to do with Docker or acme.json?

Comment: have you tried turning off IPV6?